# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't create Engine at com.google.android.filament.Engine.create(Engine.java:46)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-11

i'm facing this error when ever open android studio after update to 3.6

```
   Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't create Engine
         at com.google.android.filament.Engine.create(Engine.java:46)
          at com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin.viewer.Filamentor$3.run(Filamentor.java:103)

    -----
    JRE 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre
```

[Here is error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2OkP.png)

**JDK 11.0.1**

**Android Studio 3.6**

Any one have idea about it? it will be really helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is related to sceneform plugin Go to: C:\Users.....AndroidStudio3.6\config\plugins and delete google-sceneform-tools folder I solved it this way

Comment: after restarting the error gone but again next restart it comes again, and then after delete this folder it fixed,